# cannot upload customize tabs in microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I download a teams tab sample, follow its guideline, I found I cannot find "View teams" in step 3

Even I choose Manage team, there is also no entrance to upload the tab sample, who can tell me where it is.

#### Add the tab to Microsoft Teams

1. Download the [tab app dev package](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-todo/raw/before-final/package/todo.dev.zip) zip file for this sample.
2. Create a new team for testing, if necessary. Click **Create team** at the bottom of the left-hand panel.
3. Select the team from the left-hand panel, select **... (more options)** and then select **View Team**.
4. Select the **Developer (Preview)** tab, and then select **Upload**.
5. Navigate to the downloaded zip file from step 1 above and select it.
6. Go to any channel in the team.  Click the '+' to the right of the existing tabs.
7. Select your tab from the gallery that appears.
8. Accept the consent prompt.
9. If needed, sign in using your Office 365 work/school account.  Note that the code will try to do silent authentication if possible.
10. Validate authentication information.
11. Hit Save to add the tab to channel.

Comment: Have you followed the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/sideload?

Comment: Those are ancient, obsolete instructions, Mike Zhang. Where did you find them? Marc's link are the correct instructions.